# Why is CGO_ENABLED=1 default?

Tags: go

CGO_ENABLED=1 I believe is the current default which means that it depends on GLIBC which can have breaking changes between updates & distributions.

CGO_ENABLED=0 is the workaround for creating static standalone binaries, so why isn't this the default?

Comment: "is the workaround for creating static standalone binaries" --- it's not enough, in general case.

Comment: Sometimes you need cgo sometimes you don't. More often I do. Why should a default  be different to what I need regularly? The question is highly opinion based.

Comment: Opinion based? Can't I expect Go binaries to be **static and portable**?

Comment: libc is mostly portable, and users that need it will need it. If you use something more specific with cgo, then you likely can’t disable it anyway.

Comment: Well I honestly didn't expect to hit 'GLIBC_2.32' not found when deploying my Go "static binary" to AWS's Lambda runtime.

Comment: "Can't I expect Go binaries to be static and portable" --- you can expect, there is no portable way to do that though: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26492

Comment: Go libraries are statically linked, but there's no claim that every go binary is static. Searching for info static go binaries brings up loads of sites describing all the relevant details.

Answer (score 28):

In general, `CGO_ENABLED=1` leads to faster, smaller builds & runtimes - as it can dynamically load the host OS's native libraries (e.g. `glibc`, DNS resolver etc.) - when running on the build OS. This is ideal for local rapid development. For deployment, `CGO_ENABLED=1` may not be practical or even possible - when considering the deployment hosting OS.

If you're purely using the standard library, they you may not necessarily need CGO enabled. In certain standard libraries behavior will different if using a pure-Go version (`CGO_ENABLED=0`) or a CGO-enabled version:

- [net](https://golang.org/pkg/net/): see DNS [Name Resolution](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution)
- [os/users](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/):

  - `CGO_ENABLED=1` uses the native OS (e.g. on Linux `nsswitch`) for ID lookup
  - `CGO_ENABLED=0` uses a basic Go implementation (e.g. reads from `/etc/passwd`) - which does not include other ID registries the host may be aware of

**Deployment**

While a `CGO_ENABLED=1` binary may be smaller in size, it relies on delivering a host OS too. Comparing Docker images:

- `ubuntu:20.04` is  73.9MB (`glibc`: GNU-libc)
- `alpine:3.12.1` is  5.57MB (`musl` libc)

so adding an OS (even a minimal one) adds this extra baggage. `alpine` looks attractive in its minimal size - but its `libc` may not be compatible with packages that rely on `glibc`.

`CGO_ENABLED=0` is, however, ideal for [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) docker image deployments - as no host OS needs to be bundled.

However, if your application imports a package with C-code (e.g. [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)) then your build *must* enable CGO.

Comment: "as it dynamically loads the host OS's native glibc" ? Can you elaborate? How do you know? Why? On which OS?

Comment: "In general, CGO_ENABLED=1 leads to faster, smaller builds & runtimes", no, that is _not_ why libc is linked. Not counting when a 3rd party packages is using cgo for something, it is used for some very specific use cases by the std library, but most of the time you are using glibc which you do not want to statically link anyway.

Comment: @JimbB I'm not sure I follow your comment - can you expand please? I covered some examples of subtle `CGO` vs. non-`CGO` behavior in the std library.

Comment: You have multiple conflated pieces here, and none of them have to do with " faster, smaller builds & runtimes". The default use of the host libc is for features that cannot be duplicated in the std lib. `CGO_ENABLED=1` is default because it is -- it doesn't need be, but it was decided that would be the most useful default. It does not speed up _anything_. It is slower to link in C libraries because you're doing more work to build it. It is slower to call C libraries, because switching stacks takes some time. It has nothing to do with local development vs deployment, you use whichever you need.

Comment: and `CGO_ENABLED=1` will not make your binary smaller, in fact it usually makes it slightly larger because it has to compile in the extra code to handle cgo and whatever else that cgo code is doing.