# golang build fails because of gcc being required

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am building the following ridiculously simple `go` program

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
)

const namespace = "default"

func main() {
    home := homedir.HomeDir()
    defaultKubeConfigPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", home, ".kube/config")
    kubeconfig := flag.String("kubeconfig", defaultKubeConfigPath, "location to kubeconfig file")
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := range pods.Items {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", pods.Items[i].Name)
    }

    deployments, err := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := range deployments.Items {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", deployments.Items[i].Name)
    }
}
```

using the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:1.19.2-alpine3.15 as builder

COPY src /src

WORKDIR /src

RUN go build -race -ldflags "-s -w" -a -o client-go

FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder client-go /client-go

ENTRYPOINT [ "./client-go" ]
```

The build fails as folows:

```
#8 21.92 # runtime/cgo
#8 21.92 cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Where exactly is `gcc` needed since I am not using any `cgo` extensions?

Is there an a priori way of identifying when `gcc` for `cgo` is needed?

Comment: Try it without `-race`.  I've found that the race detector may need gcc.  (This may not be true of all architectures and Go versions.)

Comment: Take a look at the go mod file to see how your "ridiculously simple go program" is ridiculously complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `CGO_ENABLED=0` and not enable the race detector.

---

> The cgo tool is enabled by default for native builds on systems where it is expected to work. It is disabled by default when cross-compiling. You can control this by setting the CGO_ENABLED environment variable when running the go tool: set it to 1 to enable the use of cgo, and to 0 to disable it. The go tool will set the build constraint "cgo" if cgo is enabled. The special import "C" implies the "cgo" build constraint, as though the file also said "// +build cgo". Therefore, if cgo is disabled, files that import "C" will not be built by the go tool.

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo

See also [Why is CGO_ENABLED=1 default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531437/why-is-cgo-enabled-1-default)

With `CGO_ENABLED=0` and the race flag set, you'll get an error:

```
#8 0.857 go: -race requires cgo; enable cgo by setting CGO_ENABLED=1
```

---

So to get this to compile without gcc you'll want to use:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -o client-go
```